# Configurable Map Viewer (CMV) - select by drawing polygon around points, then average the values of the points

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, configurable-map-viewer

I have seen this question and have tried the code suggested:
[Adapting ESRI ArcGIS API for JavaScript Feature Layer With Selection sample for use in Configurable Map Viewer (CMV)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115229/adapting-esri-arcgis-api-for-javascript-feature-layer-with-selection-sample-for)

But I have been unable to get it to work. I also want to change the result from the sum to the average.

Here is my error report from chrome development tools
[image: My error report]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first issue: it appears that the template file for your widget is missing, inaccessible or corrupt. Based on the code posted in the linked example, the template file is `'./Select/templates/Select.html'`. Check that file to ensure it is valid.

For your second issue: to do a simple average, you would take the sum calculated in the example code `this.productionSum` and divide by the number of features `event.features.length`. Something like:

```
this.productionAVG = (this.productionSum / event.features.length)
```

Be sure to handle a possible divide by zero error in the cases where no features are returned by the selection.

Comment: tmcgee answered the second half of this question in [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129695/configurable-map-viewer-cmv-average-the-values-of-the-points)