# Configurable Map Viewer (CMV) - average the values of the points

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, configurable-map-viewer

I have been able to select points and find the sum of the points. What I really need is to **average** the points.
 Here is my (acquired from someone else) code for finding the sum.

```
define([
'dojo/_base/declare',
'dijit/_WidgetBase',
'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
'dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin',
'esri/toolbars/draw',
'esri/InfoTemplate',
'esri/layers/FeatureLayer',
'esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol',
'esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol',
'esri/Color',
'esri/tasks/query',
'dijit/form/Button',
'dojo/_base/lang',
'dojo/on',
'dojo/_base/array',
'dojo/dom',
'dojo/text!./Select/templates/Select.html',
'xstyle/css!./Select/css/Select.css'
], function (declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, Draw, InfoTemplate, FeatureLayer, SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, Color, Query, Button, lang, on, arrayUtil, dom, SelectTemplate, css) {
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
        widgetsInTemplate: true,
        templateString: SelectTemplate,
        selectTools: null,

        postCreate: function () {
            this.selectTools = new Draw(this.map);

            this.selectQuery = new Query();

            on(this.selectTools, "DrawEnd", lang.hitch(this, function (geometry) {
                this.selectTools.deactivate();
                this.selectQuery.geometry = geometry;

                this.featureLayer.selectFeatures(this.selectQuery,
                FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW);
            }));
this.fieldsSelectionSymbol =
             new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 10,
new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
new Color([255,0,0]), 1),
new Color([0,255,0,0.25]));


            var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate(this.title, this.content);

            this.featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(this.featureLayerURL,
            {
                mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
                infoTemplate: infoTemplate,
                outFields: ["*"]
            });

            this.featureLayer.setDefinitionExpression(this.defExpress);
            this.featureLayer.setSelectionSymbol(this.fieldsSelectionSymbol);
            this.featureLayer.on("selection-complete", lang.hitch(this, 'sumGasProduction'));
            var clearMsg = this.clearSelectMsg;
            this.featureLayer.on("selection-clear", function () {
                dom.byId('messages').innerHTML = "<i>" + clearMsg + "</i>";
            });

            this.map.addLayer(this.featureLayer);

        },

        select: function () {
            this.selectTools.activate(Draw.EXTENT);
        },
        clearSelection: function () {
            this.featureLayer.clearSelection();
        },


        sumGasProduction: function (event) {
                        var productionSum = 0;
                        var sumField = this.fieldToSum;

                        arrayUtil.forEach(event.features, function (feature) {
                            productionSum += feature.attributes[sumField];

                        });
                        dom.byId('messages').innerHTML = "<b>" + this.selectSumMsgPrefix + " " + productionSum + " " + this.selectSumUnits + ". </b>";
                    }
    });
});
```

Secondly my clear selection button is not working.

---

Here is my code for clear selection:

```
<div data-dojo-attach-point="clearSelection" class="clearSelection">

    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button"  data-dojo-attach-event="onClick:clearSelection" >
        Clear your Selection
    </button>
</div>
```

I have no idea how to get the average. I was trying to use what you said in another answer but I could not figure it out. I have found an example that does find the average

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/query_bypoly.html

```
      function average(fset, att) {
    var features = fset.features;
    var sum = 0;
    var featuresLength = features.length;
    for (var x = 0; x < featuresLength; x++) {
      sum = sum + features[x].attributes[att];
    }
    return Math.round(sum/featuresLength);
  }
```

Comment: I provided an answer for calculating the average in your [previous question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129543/configurable-map-viewer-cmv-select-by-drawing-polygon-around-points-then-av)

Comment: Yes I saw that and am grateful! But was unable to get that to work. I kept getting an error of " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: please show your complete code where you are attempting to calculate the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide the template HTML for your button so this is just a guess as to the issue. Your button needs an 'onClick' event to execute your 'clearSelection' method. Something like this:

```
data-dojo-attach-event="onClick:clearSelection"
```

To display an average instead of a sum, you can use the original method you posted with a slight variation:

```
avgGasProduction: function (event) {
    var productionSum = 0, productionAvg = 0;
    var sumField = this.fieldToSum;

    arrayUtil.forEach(event.features, function (feature) {
        productionSum += feature.attributes[sumField];
    });

    if (event.features && event.features.length > 0) {
        productionAvg = Math.round(productionSum / event.features.length)
    }

    dom.byId('messages').innerHTML = "<b>" + this.selectSumMsgPrefix + " " + productionAvg + " " + this.selectSumUnits + ". </b>";
}
```

Comment: I updated the original question to include the HTML for the clearSelection button

Comment: Using chrome, do you get any error messages in the browser console? Add a console.log('test') statement to your clearSelection method to verify that the method is actually being called from the button click.

Comment: I keep getting the error:
"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: The HTML code for the button you posted is in your template file "./Select/templates/Select.html"?

Comment: Yes, It is in the same place that I have the code to find the sum of the points and that button works.

Comment: I believe I see the issue now in the code you posted for the button. Your template has data-dojo-attach-point="clearSelection". This attach point has the same name as the method you are  attempting to call in the button click "onClick:clearSelection". Change the name of the attach point.